# Is it possible to route network traffic according to user ID?

Tags: linux-networking

On my Debian system, I'd like one of my users to use a different network interface as their default route for all internet traffic.  I know how to use iptables to block the other interfaces, but not how to set the default route so it affects only them.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at the iptables man page show support for an `owner` module for setting up rules based on user and/or group ID's. It only works for locally generated packets (i.e. not on the router managing traffic from different workstations).

Then a policy based routing setup comes to mind, combining to something like:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o owner --uid-owner <uid> -j MARK --set-mark 21

ip rule add fwmark 21 table 22
ip route add default via <alternate_gateway> table 22
```

UNTESTED!

The numbers of the firewall mark (21) and routing table identifier (22) are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

According to user ID seems a bit difficult (are they connecting to your server via SSH, or just using it as a router?), you could quite easily do it by IP or MAC address, if you have control of your network.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to place part of the process tree in a separate network namespace through the use of `CLONE_NEWNET`. Each namespace work as an independent network stack. Each network interface can be used in just one namespace at a time. Packets between the network namespaces can be send using virtual network interfaces.

I can't tell from your question, if this is a suitable solution for you.